# My daughter does not take solid food. She is one year old

Tags: food

I have a one-year-old daughter. She takes only milk and denies taking solids or other things. When I usually keep trying to give her some solids, she immediately throws them away or spits them from her mouth. What can I do for her?

Comment: Is she healthy? Thriving? Or wasting away?

Comment: Have you tried giving her just rice cereal mixed with milk?  Start with a very thin mix and work towards thicker to get her used to the texture, while it still tastes like the milk she knows and loves.  I guess a good point to clarify - What solid foods are you attempting?

Comment: Hi and welcome!As implied by the above questions, more information is often welcome. :) If we know more, a more suitable answer is likely to result.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that her growth (size & weight) are normal for her age. If that's not the case, please go and contact your doctor / go to the hospital!

What you see is a normal reflex (assuming the above) and that's nothing to worry about. New food has a different taste than milk and that takes time to get used to.

With regards to the practical side of introducing solid food, we decided to follow the method of [Rapley](http://www.rapleyweaning.com/index.php) ([Kleintjes](https://www.borstvoeding.com/medewerkers/stefan-kleintjes.html) is a related method, but that link is only in Dutch). [Here](http://www.rapleyweaning.com/assets/blw_guidelines.pdf) are some quick pointers.

In short: each time we prepare food, we keep some food aside for her. This is cooked or steamed and has no seasoning on them. When we start eating, we give her her own plate and then we just let her discover the food (shape, taste & how it feels when it's crushed in her mighty fists). Be aware that it can be very messy!

Answer (score 0):

As long as your daughter is healthy, this might be part of her learning about food. Babies love reactions from adults, they love to feel foods go in and out of their mouths, and they may enjoy messes.

However, my baby (who is now a very healthy 5 year old) refused to eat any baby food I bought when he weaned. I sniffed it and most of it did smell unpleasant, to the point where I did not want to taste it myself!

Of course he needed to eat. So, a bit desperate, I bought vegetables and steamed them, then blended them up and froze them. I thawed them for his meals. My pediatrician recommended I add tons of butter in the steamed vegetables, because my baby was very skinny during this picky period, but of course ask yours what is healthy for your baby. Baby also drank tons of cow milk for this.